# Remove header a footer white bars of react-native-qrcode-scanner

Tags: react-native

I can’t find a way to remove the white bars on the header and footer. I tried the cameraProps with different ratio but nothing works, any help please.

Answer (score 0):

try to add styles for top and bottom sections

```
 render() {
    return (
      <QRCodeScanner
        onRead={this.onSuccess}
        topViewStyle={{height: 0}}
        bottomViewStyle={{height: 0}}
      />
    );
  }
```